# Correct way to use the people picker and Rich Text

Tags: list, list-view, custom-list, people-picker, user-controls

I'd like to have a custom form that lets me add items to a list.

There are two fields giving me trouble.

One is a "Moderators" field which will use a people picker.

The other is a "Body" field, which is a Rich text zone.

The problem is, I cannot get either to work properly. Should I give up making a custom page and just link to a standard, slightly stylized NewItem.aspx page? Some kind of a standard SP List View webpart?

**Background for those unfamiliar:**
There is no people picker control, you have to hack together a lot of Javascript, and the Rich Text Editor web parts (of which there are a few, the most popular being an InputFormTextBox) only works in IE and is therefore unacceptable. I cannot use a Telerik control for this one, sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest - modify/create one NewItem.aspx, from designer detach from page layout and design like you wish :) you can almost achieve a perfect design not just "slightly stylized"

Comment: Is this deployable? It's going inside a Site Definition, so the GUID's being used may not be constant.